# tag friend when adding new facebook open graph story

Tags: facebook

I'm still using Facebbok api V.1 and when I add a new open graph story I want to tag a friend...

Can I do that using Facebook version 1 api only?

I'm asking this because I understand I need the user token to tag a friend and not the `user_id`... and the only way to retrieve the token is calling `/taggable_friends` (api v2) but at the moment I can't do that because I can't match results (I've `user_id` and I can't understand which is the corresponding token)

Is there a way to get the `friend_token` from the real `user_id`?

Comment: No there is no way to get a tag_token from a user id. But because the user is selecting the friend they can just select out of taggable_friends instead of /me/friends

Comment: And is there a way to tag friends using the api v1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the token to tag a friend since you are using v1 API. Just go about as normal and retrieve the user id from `/me/friends` the same way as from before v2 was released.

Comment: Are you sure? Because reading Facebook Doc it seems the Open Graph story tagging capability works only with user_token and not user_id...

Comment: @EnricoPiccini yes I'm sure as long as you are using a v1 app

Comment: Ok, maybe for me it doesn't worked well because I tried to tag a Friend and he's not a developer and I hadn't the FB permission to TAG friend in Open Graph Action... Thank you

Comment: @enrico if your friend does not have developer access and your permission to tag has not been approved yet, then it definitely will not work that is how it's designed